Exported variable has or is using name 'UNDEFINED_VOID_ONLY' from external module error
I have a Next.js project that I publish to npm. I have a simple Component that I export from the library.
// material-ui
import { styled, Theme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { Box } from "@mui/material";

// ==============================|| DRAWER HEADER - STYLED ||============================== //

interface Props {
  theme: Theme;
  open: boolean;
}

const DrawerHeaderStyled = styled(Box, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "open",
})(({ theme, open }: Props) => ({
  ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
  display: "flex",
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: open ? "flex-start" : "center",
  paddingLeft: theme.spacing(open ? 3 : 0),
}));

export default DrawerHeaderStyled;


When i run npm run build it comes with error :

./app/layout/MainLayout/Drawer/DrawerHeader/DrawerHeaderStyled.ts:13:7
Type error: Exported variable 'DrawerHeaderStyled' has or is using name 'UNDEFINED_VOID_ONLY' from external module "/Users/trkas/VSCodeProjects/ng-frontend/node_modules/@types/react/canary" but cannot be named.

I cannot see what I can do about this error, unless removing the declaration: true in my tsconfig.json, but as i publish this project as an npm package i want it to be true.
tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "declaration": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "hooks/*": ["app/hooks/*"],
      "utils/*": ["app/utils/*"],
      "types/*": ["app/types/*"],
      "components/*": ["app/components/*"],
      "store": ["app/store"],
      "store/*": ["app/store/*"],
      "services/*": ["app/services/*"],
      "sections/*": ["app/sections/*"],
      "api/*": ["app/api/*"],
      "data/*": ["app/data/*"]
    },
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
        // Transform paths in output .js files
      }
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "app/**/*",
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}


I am using Next.js 14.2.1 and @mui/material 5.15.15
I have tried with removing the declaration:true in tsconfig.json and it would build. But I would like to use the declaration: true because the other TypeScript projects that use my library won't have access to the types and interfaces defined in the code. This means they won't get the benefits of type checking and autocompletion when using my library.
I was just expecting it to build without errors

I found out that the issue arises when installing @types/react@18.2.69 so version < 69 works..? any ideas why and what to do about it?

Any luck on this one? I am getting the same error.

Thank you so much. Instaling @types/react@18.2.68 works. Finally got a workaround! Thank you!!
